# Rails trying to build nested models but getting rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, attributes

I am not sure why this is happening, but I am trying to create nested attributes with `Company` and `URLs` models.

Here's what I have:

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy
end
```

.

```
# app/models/url.rb
class Url < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Company
end
```

.

and so for example, I have this:

```
urls = [{:url=>"http://audit.site.com/"},
 {:url=>"http://bidboard.site.com/"},
 {:url=>"http://careers.sit.com/"}]
```

and I'm trying to create a new Company with these URLs associated with them by doing the following:

```
company = Company.new(company_name: @report_data[:company_name], domain: @report_data[:domain])
company.urls.build(urls)
company.save
```

and I am getting a rollback error from the console and not sure why. I am sure this should be relatively simple. Basically, the user submits company name to this form and kicks off this process.

My migration records should be OK from what I understand. Here they are:

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :company_name
      t.string :domain

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :urls do |t|
      t.belongs_to :company, foreign_key: true
      t.string :url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

So after calling `company.errors`, this is what I see:

```
 @base=#<Company:0x00007f71800f0e80 id: nil, company_name: "Random", domain: "random.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @details=
  {:urls=>
    [{:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     {:error=>:invalid},
     ...
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `company.errors` after calling `company.save`

Comment: I tried reproducing this and its working fine. Try call  `company.save!` instead as it will raise an error if the record is invalid.

Comment: AFAIK `company.urls.build` takes a hash (url object), not an array of hashes.

Comment: @adbeel `.new, .build, .create` etc all take an array of hashes. This creates/initializes serveral records at the same time. "The attributes parameter can be either a Hash or an Array of Hashes. These Hashes describe the attributes on the objects that are to be created." https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create

Comment: I had a typo. FML. I got it fixed. Thanks so much guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `inverse_of` when using nested attributes

Basically your associations would be like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :company
end

class Url < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :urls
end
```

Go through this [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to understand better

Also i would suggest you to use `save!` in order to see why something is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your server logs, ensure have you:

1. Added a foreign_key to Url Model.
2. White listed params in Company Controller.